# UIView animation not working - Xcode (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

Example: 
I don't see any animation. Why?

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
    self.buttonTrial.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
}, completion: { completion in
    self.buttonTrial.transform = .identity
})
```

Comment: Will be needing a lot more information! What are you trying to do for starters? Is there `autoLayout`? What is your UI like?

Comment: @Rikh I use storyboard, I want to get the effect of pulsating animation

Comment: One thing, having a completion block is unnecessary since its a repeat animation, the completion block wont be called anyways. But that shouldn't stop the animation from working. Apart from that, the code seems fine and should work.

Comment: Do you trigger this animation block in your code? E.g. on buttonTrial tap?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. I removed the `completion` as it is not needed, but apart from that, this was done with *exactly* the code you've shown.

[image]